# Dimensionality mismatch in Keras Model with multiple input multiple output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a dataset (in tabular form) that contains 192 rows and 24 columns. My goal is to use this dataset as a training dataset to forecast (regression) the 24 values from every column for several steps in the future. The figure below represents the idea:

[image]

As mentioned the dataset has 192 rows and 24 columns. The idea is to use 20 steps/samples (rows) to predict the next 5 steps (rows). I will skip the part with initial data preprocessing and loading and will strat with the normalization stage:

```
df_training = scaler.fit_transform(df_training)
print(df_training.shape[0], df_training.shape[1])
```

The output dimension is as expected (192, 24). Then I prepare the dataset to be fed to the Keras model. The goal is to have the X_train dataset of dimension 168, 20, 24 (20, see the figure, is the number of steps used to make prediction) and y_train dataset of dimension 168, 5, 24 (5, see the figure, is the number of steps that need to be predicted):

```
def split_series(series, n_past, n_future):


  X, y = list(), list()
  for window_start in range(len(series)):
      past_lim = window_start + n_past
      future_lim = past_lim + n_future
      if future_lim > len(series):
          break
      past, future = series[window_start:past_lim, ], series[past_lim:future_lim, ]
    
      X.append(past)
      y.append(future)
  return np.array(X), np.array(y)
```

Then I apply the function to get the X_train and y_train:

```
X_train, y_train = split_series(df_training, 20, 5)
```

This results in X_train of dimension 168,20,24 and y_train of dimension 168,5,24.
Then I do the reshaping:

```
X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[1]))
y_train = y_train.reshape((y_train.shape[0], y_train.shape[1], y_train.shape[2]))
```

The output is then 168,24,20 and 168,24,5.
Afterwards I set the input and output dimensions for the Keras model:

```
inp_dim = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])
out_dim = y_train.shape[2]
```

The result is (24,20) and (24).
During the next and the final step I initiate the training process (I am planning to use LSTM, as it performs well for regression-related problems. The model is not very advanced, it is here just for the demonstration purposes):

```
# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape = (inp_dim), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(24))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=5, verbose=0)
```

This results in an error:

```
Incompatible shapes: [3,5,24] vs. [3,24]
 [[{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_39943]
```

I assume that I have some problems with dimensions. I've found plenty tutorials that explain  how to predict just one value based on multiple input or single input / single output cases. But I am still struggling to understand how to properly manage dimensions in the case of multiple input / multiple output. I would appreciate any help and advices to adjust the dimensions. Thank you in advance!